# Using form in object_detail

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

This has me stumped. (But I'm new at this.) The generic view object_detail is called with a queryset and the id field of interest. When object_detail then renders the template it is done with the template_object_name. When I write the template I use the template_object_name and can display all the fields. OK, that's nice, but I have a form I made with ModelForm.

So how do I get the form to show up? I've looked around for this. I tried passing the form in extra_context so that the form could accept the data in the object that is used to render the template, but no go.

The workaround is just writing a view. The problem with object_detail is that the SQL that pull out the row by specified id is done inside object_detail and then the object goes to the view. If I'm interested in using the form that I created with ModelForm then I want to set a form=mymodelForm(object) and pass form to the template for rendering. Another way to ask my question is where is the hook in object_detail that specifies what kind of object is specified?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. If you want to display the form to edit the object, have you considered using the `update_object` generic view instead?

Comment: Oh, I can display the form and enter data or do the edit. It is the issue of what does one do with an object_detail view? The template gets an object when using object_detail. It is nice that that database gets queried and the correct object is delivered to the template. I am able to display the fields if I lay them out in the template. However, it seems there should be a way for a generic view to show all the fields of a class when displayed by object_detail. After all, with a form class you can just put in a variable in the template like {{ form }} and magically the whole form erupts.

Comment: What gets rendered where you write `{{ object }}` in a template depends on your model's `__unicode__` method. You could conceivably write it such that nicely formatted HTML comes out, but that violates loose coupling (if you wanted to change the way the object is presented, you'd have to go and mess with the model, as opposed to the template -- also, the `__unicode__` representation is used in other places, like the interactive shell, and the admin interface). Forms let you do that because they're designed to work with the template language (they are already part of the presentation layer).

Comment: I used the unicode identifier for showing name and date of birth for my individuals, and that worked nicely for the list view.  How about this - can I subclass from object_detail and use a form mixin to create a customized generic view that will get the form to show up?

Comment: Thanks to all about this. I/ve answered the question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/6564068/820321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is available on [Using class based generic view DetailView with a ModelForm reveals a bug - how to proceed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6564068/820321)

Thanks to everyone.  The comments to the related questions allowed me to figure this out. Couldn't have done this without you!